# How to manage desktop icon spacing using terminal in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: desktop-environments, .desktop

How to set custom desktop icon spacing using terminal or any other way in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS? I want to reduce the spaces between the desktop icons to fit more icons into the desktop in a nice looking way. I am using nemo file manager, and have observed this problem in both nemo and nautilus file manager. I have searched over the internet, but have not found any fruitful answer. Hoping for fruitful answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can align/save/restore the desktop icons on 14.04 if you are using nautilus as your file manager ... There is a script/app to do this .. Just download Happy Desktop at gnomefiles.org.   The script can align the desktop icons to a grid that you define by setting the number of icons per row and icons per column you would like for your desktop.  The icon positions are then adjusted to the nearest grid points.  It's free!