# Arrange Icons In Better Grid

Tags: unity, icons

I've recently come to find all my desktop programs and icons thrown askew about the place, and while rearranging, I noticed that the grid system Ubuntu uses by default is (in my eyes) miserable.

On Windows for example there is a large grid, and icons are far enough from each other to read, but not too close, and Ubuntu doesn't seem to - by default - have a vertical grid, just horizontal.

The following is what I currently am facing, either icons are way too close:

[image]

Or they are way too far apart:

[image]

*(Note: no icons will fit in the middle of those 2)*

What I want is a icon grid identical (or at least the closest you can get) to what Windows has (see the following picture):

[image]

Is there a way I can do this, either via installation of program(s) or in Ubuntu Settings?

***What I've tried so far:***

1. As [suggested](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/32470755#32470755) by @KazWolfe, I should check "Keep aligned," which did activate the grid system, but again not my cup of tea.
2. As [suggested](https://askubuntu.com/questions/827940/arrange-icons-in-better-grid?noredirect=1#comment1259765_827940) by @WinEunuuchs2Unix I took off "Keep aligned" and dragged the icons free range, but again was not was I was looking for.

Comment: I have two icon/shortcuts on my desktop and just move them to where I want them and they stay there. So I don't share your grievances. This sounds like a feature request for Ubuntu snap to grid?  Can you elaborate on "not my cup of tea"? Perhaps others can answer if you explain why 1 1/2 lumps of sugar are better than one lump or two.

Comment: As stated in the question, the perfect 1 1/2 lumps would be the grid system  that Windows has, where There is an X,Y location marked for every possible location an icon can go, and an icon could not go into any other position @WinEunuuchs2Unix

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What version of Ubuntu are you using?

If it is 14.04 or 16.04, someone wrote a Gnome script called [Happy Desktop](https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1195331/) that allows you to define the grid size that controls how your desktop icons are spaced. I found out about it in a [similar question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/621418/how-to-manage-desktop-icon-spacing-using-terminal-in-ubuntu-14-04) on this forum.

Comment: +1. If you search on `desktop grid` here in *Ask Ubuntu* you'll find dozens of questions where your answer could apply.